# Regular expression for percentages greater than 0 and less than or equal to 100

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I searched the web and came up with:
`/(^100(\.0{1,2})?$)|(^([1-9]([0-9])?|0)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$)/`

The problem is it accepts 0.

Comment: This is where it does - `|0` - and `(\.[0-9]{1,2})?` is optional.

Comment: I think the |0 is important for 0.3 as example

Comment: Then, you need to create a separate branch for the `0.01`. Try [`^(?:100(?:\.0{1,2})?|[1-9]\d?(?:\.\d{1,2})?|0\.(?!0+$)\d{1,2})$`](https://regex101.com/r/uV3gD4/1). I think you can really convert a string into a number and then use regular comparison methods.

Comment: You are using the wrong tool for this work. Think about capturing the value using a regex but checking bounds in javascript. Even if you are able to pull this stunt using regular expressions, the code will be very obscure and harder to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are thinking about the problem wrongly. A better method if possible would be to convert the string to a double and perform the check using [arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

```
const examplePercentage = '0.5%';
const percentageAsFloat = parseFloat(examplePercentage); // 0.5
const isValid = percentageAsFloat > 0 && percentageAsFloat <= 100; // true
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
^0*(100(\.0{1,2})?|[1-9][0-9]?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?|0\.(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]?))$
```

It handles `>= 1` different from `< 1`.

**But** I would go with parsing the number and checking it's value.